# Regexp doesn't work

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

I want to convert all the deques in my python code to lists. I.e. `deque([1])` should become `[1]`. I tried `M-% deque(\(.+\)) RET \1 RET`, but it said `Replaced 0 occurences`. What's wrong with my regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `C-M-%` instead of `M-%`.  You want `query-replace-regexp`, not `query-replace`.